# AWS Lambda does not get response after 300 seconds with nodejs aws-sdk

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I was using nodejs aws-sdk to invoke a long time running Lamda function. As we know AWS has increased lambda execution time to 900 seconds. But I can not get the lamda invoke response after lamda executing 300 seconds.

**Here is the issue reproduce guid:**

AWS Lambda code (Node.js 10.x) named `error-handle`:

```js
const { promisify } = require('util')
const sleep = promisify(setTimeout)

exports.handler = async (event,context) => {
    await sleep(310000);
    return 'Success'
};
```

Lambda invoke index.js:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const main = async() =>{
  const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
    region:'ap-southeast-2',
    maxRetries: 0,
    httpOptions: {
      timeout: 600000,
    }
  });
  let result;
  try {
    result = await lambda.invoke({
      FunctionName: 'error-handle',
      InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
      Payload: ""
    }).promise();
  }catch(error){
    result = error;
  }
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}
main()
```

After I run `node index.js` and wait for `310` seconds lambda execution time. I can see the lambda has been existed successfully. But I can not get response in my `index.js`. After `600` seconds I will get timeout error according to my timeout config.

It seems AWS lambda has not increasing the execution time from `300` to `900` seconds properly with the api endpoint.

Comment: Are you using API Gateway to invoke your Lambda functions?

Comment: Don't forget to set timeout of lambda to 15 minutes

Comment: @sigmus No, I invoke the lambda directly

Comment: @Herb is it using aws cli that you are invoking the lambda

Comment: @amittn I was using javascript aws-sdk to invoke the lambda. Not the aws cli